# ¿Por qué, al utilizar el método finish(), el flujo no retorna a la actividad original?

Tags: android, android-intent

El escenario es el siguiente:

1. Desde una *aplicación A*, envío un intent explícito a una actividad de una *apllicación B*
2. Luego de procesar la información contenida en el intent, invoco al método `finish()` desde la *aplicación B* y el flujo del programa regresa a la *aplicación A*.

Este comportamiento es el esperado, sin embargo, cuando ocurre un cambio de configuración en la *apliación B*, e.g. una rotación de pantalla o cambio a night mode, al invocar el método *finish()* desde la *aplicación B* el procesamiento subsecuente en la *aplicación A* se lleva a cabo pero, **en pantalla, la aplicación B se mantiene en primer plano**.

¿Por qué sucede esto y cómo podría evitarlo?

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: "en pantalla, la aplicación B se mantiene en primer plano.", como se puede mantener si realizaste finish() en B?

Comment: @Jorgesys así es, justo esa es mi duda, pareciera que el método finish(), esta de alguna forma redireccionando a la propia actividad, ya que el resultado es que la interfaz que se mantiene en pantalla es la misma (aplicación B)